# how to show a hidden element on hover on tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

how would it be possible to display a hidden menu through a hover. im getting confused as to how a hidden element can be connected to a visible element. this example is on the headlessui website. however instead of clicking on it, would it be possible to hover to show the popover?

```
return (
  <div className='fixed w-full max-w-sm px-4 top-16'>
    <Popover className='relative'>
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <Popover.Button></Popover.Button>
          <Transition>
            <Popover.Panel className='absolute z-10 w-screen max-w-sm px-4 mt-3 transform -translate-x-1/2 left-1/2 sm:px-0 lg:max-w-3xl'></Popover.Panel>
          </Transition>
        </>
      )}
    </Popover>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: You can't get hover on a hidden element in CSS. Whether it's tailwind, bootstrap, styled components or just good old plain CSS. The element is not there for your cursor to ever "be over" in order to initiate the hover state.

Comment: I think they're asking for the hidden element to become visible when a visible element is hovered.

Comment: correct JHeth. Just found out about popper.js, disregard this post.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the onMouse in Events

```
return (
  <div onMouseEnter={() => setOpen(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setOpen(false)}

className='fixed w-full max-w-sm px-4 top-16'>
    <Popover className='relative'>
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <Popover.Button></Popover.Button>
          <Transition>
            <Popover.Panel className='absolute z-10 w-screen max-w-sm px-4 mt-3 transform -translate-x-1/2 left-1/2 sm:px-0 lg:max-w-3xl'></Popover.Panel>
          </Transition>
        </>
      )}
    </Popover>
  </div>
);
```